# How to route to back from 'next()' function in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I use Server Sent Events in connection with a node.js application. I try to implement a service which is monitoring a process on a linux machine.

So I try to get the PID of the process and use `monitor-pid` to read out some information about the process.

**What I want to achieve:**

When I found a valid PID, I call `next()` to route to the function which prints out the content of my `monitor-pid` object.

This object has a `end` listener which is invoked when the PID of the process is removed. In this `end` listener I want to go 'back' to `app.get('/')`.

I tried it with `app.redirect('/')` but this did not work because the HTTP Headers for sending Server Sent Events were already set in first route.

**Question:**

How to jump back to the function which calls `next()`? Is there something like a `before()`?

**Code:**

The `mp` object is created within `getPidSync()` function.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MonitorPid = require('monitor-pid');
var mp;

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var interval;
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    });

    var pidTmp;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
          if(typeof pidTmp === "undefined" || pidTmp === "") {
            pidTmp = getPidSync();
          } else {
            next();
          }
    }, 1000);

    req.connection.addListener("close", function () {
       if(mp != null) mp.stop();
       if(typeof interval !== 'undefined') clearInterval(interval);
     }, false);
}, function(req, res) {
    if(typeof mp !== 'undefined') {
      mp.on('monitored', function (pid, stats) {
        res.write('data:' + JSON.stringify(stats) + '\n\n');
      });
      mp.on('end', function (pid) {
        res.redirect('/');
        console.error('end', pid);
      });
    }
});

app.listen(3002, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3002');
});
```